# Google Hangouts website button

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

Is it possible to add a Google Hangouts button to my business site that when clicked on initiates a call to me? I have a business website and I would like for anyone to be able to call be like the Skype button that you can embed on your website page does. Problem that I have is I went to https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button and read and then went to the Google API Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and turned on the Google+ Hangouts API and then added my Google+ profile and my Project ID (app_id) and entered it into the html markup example(s) and embeded the code into my page and it does show the button, however, when the button is clicked, it launches the Google Hangouts program and asks to invites someone.

I need to this to actually start call me because the customer at my webpage, when they click the button and the Hangouts program launches, they are not going to know what to enter here. Needs to work like the Skype call button does and actually call me.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!!

-Billy

Answer (score 3):

@Billy I'm not sure what's changed since the other answers here, but I'm actually having some success with this approach :

```
script(type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js")
.g-hangout(data-render="createhangout",
           data-invites="[{id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_PLUS_ID', invite_type: 'PROFILE'}]")
```

Where `YOUR_GOOGLE_PLUS_ID` is the number (not your vanity id) found in your profile url. Since my google plus url contains my vanity id, I obtained my `YOUR_GOOGLE_PLUS_ID` easily from the 'profile' link in the left sidebar.

Once clicked, the workflow goes like this :

1. Visitor clicks the "start hangout" button
2. the hangout app launches (chrome, android, etc)
3. they are prompted to join, they click join
4. they are prompted to invite you to the hangout. they do so.
5. you are notified to join.

The next problem I'm experiencing is that step five only seems to occur on the Google Chrome hangout Extension and roughly five minutes later in an email. Meaning no notifications on: Google+ Website, Android Hangout App, Android Google Plus App.

So it seems that this particular situation is as solved as it could be from the "integrate into a website" point of view, the remaining issue is most likely a bug with the google-plus/hangout ecosystem itself.

By the way, instead of using a `YOUR_GOOGLE_PLUS_ID` you can use the email address of that google-plus user :

```
script(type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js")
.g-hangout(data-render="createhangout",
           data-invites="[{id: 'your.google+email.address@gmail.com', invite_type: 'EMAIL'}]")
```

Although I'm not sure if this means that notification is via email only.

Comment: do you have a link to your work in progress we can see in (somewhat) action @airtonix

Comment: @airtonix: please make the workflow: 1) Visitor clicks the "start hangout" button 2) the hangout app launches (chrome, android, etc) 
a) they are prompted to join and automatically, they join b) you are notified to join. if this workflow is not possible can you open BUG issue in Hangout and as community we all vote for that feature.

Answer (score 1):

This was the basis of the process but i couldn't workout some of the code in order to rewrite it fully. [adding hangouts button to your website](http://youtu.be/Al4SbeVyLm4)

in another video, there was an element of this which would allow the caller to PAY you for the call/knowle

this one might be helpful too:
[hangouts telephone apo](http://gusclass.com/blog/2014/01/14/using-the-hangouts-telephone-api/)

Comment: Please put working example. Answers in SO has to be 100% buletproof answers, do not leave them like lazy answer kindly.

Answer (score 1):

This is now a fully supported feature.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<g:hangout render="createhangout"></g:hangout>
```

See the documentation for more detail: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button.

Answer (score 0):

I asked same question on: [How to use Google Hangout / on Air as a "contact me" feature on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457345/how-to-use-google-hangout-on-air-as-a-contact-me-feature-on-a-website) and got an answer that the feature request is under process. The complete answer here:

Currently, there is no API call to provide this functionality. You can see the following feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=678

The feature request was accepted on the 8th of December 2013 and knowing how feature requests tend to work, I'd expect it sometime between now and 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I so want this too, however a middle ground I'm finding is,

1. Add a Google Hangout button to your page https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button
2. Write your obfuscated Hangout Address next to it, http://www.fingerlakesbmw.org/main/flobfuscate.php

   `<p>Invite me, &#104;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#64;&#100;&#97;&#110;&#99;&#111;&#117;&#114;&#115;&#101;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#46;&#117;&#107;</p>`

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>`

   `<g:hangout render="createhangout"></g:hangout>`

Thanks, DanC

Comment: did you figure this out dan?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-div3"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div3', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'invites' : "[{'id': 'youremail@whatever.com','invite_type': 'EMAIL'},{'id': 'anotheremail@gmail.com','invite_type': 'EMAIL'}]",
    'widget_size': 175
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from here: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#initial_app_parameters for google hangout button.

Comment: #Soyab : Short and simple answer, Good.

Comment: #Divyesh for viewing this.