# How to use Google Hangout / on Air as a "contact me" feature on a website

Tags: javascript, html, google-hangouts

I have a Wi-Fi enabled android phone with Google Hangout installed in it and Google Hangout plugin installed on Chrome and Firefox. I want to use the Google Hangout or Google Hangout on Air on my website as a "contact me" widget/feature so that any user can click on it and start chat/video/audio etc. with me. What is the code to do it? I know it is a very dumb question, but it read their manual: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button and I could not see where to add my gmail address in the `<script>` code. Does it not need my gmail address? Because how would Google Hangout connect my website visitors to me? My website visitors should not be required to add my name/email after clicking Hangout button. There must be some parameter/code to connect to me by default (website owner).

For example, I have skype installed on my computer and phone. So, when a person clicks on "contact me" button of skype on my website contact page, I get a call or chat on phone and computer and if I am on computer then I reply from it otherwise from phone. The skype code is: `skype:<username>?call` or `skype:<username>?call` where `<username>` is my skype username. Is the same possible using Google Hangout / Google Hangout on Air?

Sharing email address is not an issue. But visitors should not be required to add my name/email after clicking Hangout button. There must be some parameter/code to connect to me by default (website owner).

Note: Google had a Gtalk widget before but Gtalk is discontinued, so I am looking for something similar from google.

Comment: I'd really like to know how to do it without giving away your email address!

Comment: @Liath Sharing email address is not an issue. But visitors should not be required to add my name/email after clicking Hangout button. There must be some parameter/code to connect to me by default (website owner)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Hangouts website button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348870/google-hangouts-website-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no API call to provide this functionality. You can see the following feature request: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=678

The feature request was accepted on the 8th of December 2013 and knowing how feature requests tend to work, I'd expect it sometime between now and 2017.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems that google does not provide any software/app/plugin/widget etc. that can work as a "contact me" feature on a website just like skype. Google had a Gtalk widget before but Gtalk is discontinued, so I am looking for something similar from google.